# ActiveMQ-CPP getDestinations() implementation

Tags: activemq-cpp

AFAIK getDestinations hasn't been implemented in the ActiveMQ-CPP api

Is there a way of getting a list of all destinations added to the broker via the C++ API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Advisory Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) to monitor activity on the Broker from the C++ client.  There are topics for Queue and Topic create / destroy along with a ton of other advisory topics for Broker events.

If you really want the getDestinations functionality in the C++ client you could contribute to the project.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'd be happy to have a look at adding getDestinations to the C++ Client.